# How to set a connection timeout on the MySQL JDBC driver?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, timeout, connection-timeout

I'm seeing the JDBC MySQL driver consistently fail connection attempts to a stopped MySQL after 10 seconds, but I'd like to change that timeout.

I tried adding ?connectTimeout=2000&socketTimeout=2000 to the connection URI, but that didn't make a difference.

Is there a way to customize how long it takes for the Driver to return a timeout while connecting to MySQL?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> I tried adding ?connectTimeout=2000&socketTimeout=2000 to the connection URI, but that didn't make a difference.

This is exactly how it's configured, eg

```
jdbc:mysql://aaa.bbb.ccc.rds.amazonaws.com:1234/hello?connectTimeout=5000&socketTimeout=30000
```

See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html .

Answer (score 7):

If neither `connectTimeout` or `socketTimeout` helps you, you can try adding `MAX_EXECUTION_TIME` to [`sessionVariables`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/connector-j-connp-props-session.html#cj-conn-prop_sessionVariables) in the URL:

```
jdbc:mysql://{host}:{port}/{database}?sessionVariables=MAX_EXECUTION_TIME=123456666
```

Query to verify:

```
SELECT @@max_execution_time
```

Expected output:

```
+--------------------+ 
|@@max_execution_time| 
+--------------------+ 
| 123456666          | 
+--------------------+
```

Answer (score 4):

Adding this before you call getConnection.

```
...
DriverManager.setLoginTimeout(2);
DriverManager.getConnection(connectString);
...
```

Worked in my case.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the connection timeout using this:

```
con.query('SET GLOBAL connect_timeout=2000')
con.query('SET GLOBAL wait_timeout=2000')
con.query('SET GLOBAL interactive_timeout=2000')
```

For more help see [MySqlConnection](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/es/connector-net-examples-mysqlconnection.html#connector-net-examples-mysqlconnection-connectiontimeout)

Answer (score -5):

You can change the default value in MySQL configuration file (connect-timeout option in mysqld section) -

```
[mysqld]
connect-timeout=100
```

If this file is not accessible for you, then you can set this value using this statement -

```
SET GLOBAL connect_timeout=100;
```

Comment: I am confused....isn't that a mysql daemon setting.  What if you want the setting to be client side.  ie. my client may not have settings from the daemon server, right?  or am I getting this wrong?

Comment: This is the setting on the MySQL server. It's not going to have any affect on a client trying to connect to that server when it's stopped.