# Configure db query timeout for quarkus application

Tags: java, mysql, quarkus, query-timeout

How to configure database query timeout?
I went through the [documentation](https://quarkus.io/guides/all-config) for all available configurations options, but seems like there is no configuration for db query timeout.

I have tried multiple combinations for configuration but those combinations are getting ignored.

Quarkus version: 2.5.4.Final 
Java version: 11.0.17

Below are the the log for some of the configurations:

```
WARN  [io.qua.config] (Quarkus Main Thread) Unrecognized configuration key "quarkus.datasource.mysql.query-timeout" was provided; it will be ignored;

WARN  [io.qua.config] (Quarkus Main Thread) Unrecognized configuration key "quarkus.datasource.db-kind.properties.javax.persistence.query.timeout" was provided; it will be ignored;

WARN  [io.qua.config] (Quarkus Main Thread) Unrecognized configuration key "quarkus.datasource.db-kind.hibernate.query-timeout" was provided; it will be ignored;

WARN  [io.qua.config] (Quarkus Main Thread) Unrecognized configuration key "quarkus.datasource.mysql.query-timeout" was provided; it will be ignored;

WARN  [io.qua.config] (Quarkus Main Thread) Unrecognized configuration key"quarkus.datasource.mysql.jdbc.queryTimeout" was provided; it will be ignored;
```

PS: I'm using "mysql" database in this application, and want to configure database query timeout from application.yml not in database layer.

Answer (score 0):

`https://quarkus.io/guides/all-config#quarkus-agroal_quarkus.datasource.jdbc.additional-jdbc-properties-additional-jdbc-properties` is the way to pass additional properties to JDCB driver.
Also check [How to set a connection timeout on the MySQL JDBC driver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21351002/how-to-set-a-connection-timeout-on-the-mysql-jdbc-driver)